# Angularjs $http interceptor pause async requests if login required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `$http` in my angularjs app.

If my api returns an unauthorised response, I show the login.

Once the user has logged in via a modal, the request interceptor then retries the `$http` request.

```
    app.factory('LoginInterceptor', function ($injector, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            var LoginModalService = $injector.get('LoginModalService'),
                $http = $injector.get('$http'),
                $location = $injector.get('$location'),
                $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),
                url = response.config.url.split('?')[0];

            if (response.data && response.data.token_status <= 0) {

                return $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then(function () {
                    return LoginModalService.show();
                }).then(function () {


                    return $http(response.config);
                }, function () {
                    $location.path('/login');

                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
            }

            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, if the multiple requests fire asynchronously the login is shown for each request.

How can I stop all other requests from executing until the user has signed in? This currently works when a single request is made. I don't want to cancel all other requests, I want them to resolve once the user has signed in.

Comment: What do you mean by "pause"? Do you want to cancel all parallel request while the modal is shown, or you want to execute them once the user has logged in?

Comment: Execute them once the user is signed in. - See edit on question

Comment: i wrote a factory for better control . have a [look](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-httpshooter)

Answer (score 0):

you could set a flag on the first unauthorized request returned, and reject all following unauthorized request/response:

```
app.factory('LoginInterceptor', function ($injector, $timeout, $q) {

    var isAuthorized = true;

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if(isAuthorized){
                 return config
            }else{
                 return $q.reject(config);
            }
        },
        response: function (response) {
            var LoginModalService = $injector.get('LoginModalService'),
                $http = $injector.get('$http'),
                $location = $injector.get('$location'),
                $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),
                url = response.config.url.split('?')[0];

            if (response.data && response.data.token_status <= 0) {

                if(isAuthorized){

                    isAuthorized = false;

                    return $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then(function () {
                        return LoginModalService.show();
                    }).then(
                        return $http(response.config);
                    }, function () {
                        $location.path('/login');

                        return $q.reject(response);
                    });
                }else{
                    return $q.reject(response)
                }

            }

            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want the requests to be rejected, I want them to resolve once the user has signed in.

Comment: then you need to store those request/response promises, say put them in an array, after user signed in, resolved all promises in that array